# Torchtext BucketIterator wrapper from tutorial produces SyntaxError

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchtext

I am following and implementing code from [this short tutorial](http://mlexplained.com/2018/02/08/a-comprehensive-tutorial-to-torchtext/) on Torchtext, which is surprisingly clear given the poor documentation of Torchtext.

When the Iterator has been created (the batch generator) he proposes to create a wrapper to produce more reusable code. (See step 5 in the tutorial).

The code contains a surprisingly long and weird line, which I don't understand and which raises a **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**. Does anyone have a clue of what is going on?

(The problematic line is the one that starts with: if self.y_vars is &amp;amp;amp;lt;g [...])

```py
class BatchWrapper:
  def __init__(self, dl, x_var, y_vars):
        self.dl, self.x_var, self.y_vars = dl, x_var, y_vars # we pass in the list of attributes for x &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;g class="gr_ gr_3178 gr-alert gr_spell gr_inline_cards gr_disable_anim_appear ContextualSpelling ins-del" id="3178" data-gr-id="3178"&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;and y&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/g&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;

  def __iter__(self):
        for batch in self.dl:
              x = getattr(batch, self.x_var) # we assume only one input in this wrapper

              if self.y_vars is &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;g class="gr_ gr_3177 gr-alert gr_gramm gr_inline_cards gr_disable_anim_appear Grammar replaceWithoutSep" id="3177" data-gr-id="3177"&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;not&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/g&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt; None: # we will concatenate y into a single tensor
                    y = torch.cat([getattr(batch, feat).unsqueeze(1) for feat in self.y_vars], dim=1).float()
              else:
                    y = torch.zeros((1))

              yield (x, y)

  def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dl)
```

Comment: So far I have changed the "if" condition for a "try/except". I don't like using a catch-all except, but other than that it seems to work fine? What I am not sure is that it is working as intended, since I don't understand the original code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I guess there is some typo from the author.
I think the correct piece of code is this:

```
if self.y_vars is not None:
    y = torch.cat([getattr(batch, feat).unsqueeze(1) for feat in self.y_vars], dim=1).float()
else:
    y = torch.zeros((1))
```

You can see this typo in the comment of line 3 also (in the code in blogpost).

Comment: This makes sense, yes, and agrees with my solution of using a try/except instead.